# android ACTION_SENDTO creates email doesn't send it

Tags: android, email, android-intent

Have working code that 1) opens an email client on an android device and 2) successfully populates all the fields needed to send a message.  This includes the to, from, subject and message body.

```
e     String mailMsg = "mailto:elmer@gmail.com" +
            "?cc="+"" +   //needed to fill out email properly
            "&subject=" + Uri.encode(subject) +
            "&body=" + Uri.encode(emailBody);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mailMsg));
    try{
        context.startActivity(emailIntent);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ae){
        Log.d("TEST100 ","Error sending email");
    }
```

Again the code works fine in terms of opening the email client, creating an populating the email message but, it does not send the email. Could it be because I have multiple email providers?  The code always manages to connect to and work with my mai based provider.

Have read the google documentation and most relevant posts in stackoverflow, is it possible to: 
1. trigger the sending of the email message without user involvement?
2. mask the display/process of creating the email?

Any information appreciated

Comment: It would certainly be weird if you could just send an email anonymously, without user interaction from a 3rd party app. So I don't think something like that exists. An easy option would be to ask the user to give you an email that you would use in your `from` email header - but that's a bit more work locally and involves a lot more work on the server side.

Comment: My plan was to ask the user if they wanted to share information with the development team.  If they said yes then fill out and send the email.  Did not want to take the users focus away from the base application.

Comment: Ok, but you could also prepare a small log server (or something like that). If you really want to do email, you can send it through an email API, such as MailGun (fairly easy to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to: trigger the sending of the email message without user involvement?

Fortunately, no.

> mask the display/process of creating the email?

Fortunately, no.

Malware authors, spammers, and the like would *love* to have the ability to send an email, without user involvement, using the user's own email account. Most users would find this behavior to be inappropriate.

If you want to send an email without user involvement, have your Web service send the email on your behalf, using your own email account and your own mail server.

Comment: point taken.  Plan / reason for question added to comments section off post.

Comment: @T.Barrett: The rationale doesn't really change the technical issue. `ACTION_SENDTO` is simply a wrapper around the same sort of `mailto:` that you use in Web development. A `mailto:` URL, which clicked upon, does not send an email. It sets up an email that the user can modify, then either send or discard at the user's discretion. Android's `ACTION_SENDTO` behaves much the same way. If you are using a third-party crash reporting and/or analytics package, it may have hooks to allow you to collect feedback without involving email.